# PHP: class.object does not show print_r()?

Tags: php

I'm trying to print class object using `print_r`.

This is my index.php code

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
    }else{
        $errusername="Enter Username";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $username=$_POST['password'];
    }else{
        $errpassword="Enter Password";

    }
    if (isset($email) &&  isset($password)) {

        $user = new User();
        print_r($user);

    }


}

 ?>
```

This is user.class.php

```
<?php
class User{

    public $id,$name,$username,$password;

    public function login()
    {
        echo "this is function";

    }

}
?>
```

I want to print class object for eg: `OBJECT([username=>this,password=>this])` It does not show any errors and does not show the `print_r` result.

Comment: it's because your variable in user object including $id,$name,$username,$password  doesn't have any value;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$username=$_POST['password'];
```

With:

```
$password=$_POST['password'];
```

As the $password var is not set the print_r is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

You are validating $email but declaring $username and other error assigning $password

```
if (isset($_POST['btnLogin'])){
    if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])){
        $username=$_POST['username'];
    }else{
        $errusername="Enter Username";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
        $password=$_POST['password'];
    }else{
        $errpassword="Enter Password";
    }
    if (isset($username) &&  isset($password)) {
        $user = new User();
        print_r($user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
echo "<pre>";
```

var_export( $user )